# How to change HTML link's href property dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Hi I have a `HTML` link on my `MVC3` View.

I want to change its `href` property each time user clicks it.

```
<a class="tabs" href="#educationDetails">
<input id="SubmitBtn" type="submit" value="Next" />
</a>
```

Is there any way to solve this issue.

Many Thanks

Comment: Use JS on the click event <input id="SubmitBtn" type="submit" value="Next" onclick="changeUrls();" />

Comment: Does the link go to another page? Or is it an internal link? Because if it goes to an external page then you'll need a server-side solution to remember the number of clicks.

Comment: Why do you have a submit button within an a-tag?

Comment: Hi @DavidThomas, it does not goes to another page. It just change the menu bar tab on same page.

Comment: That's easier then, but in what way do you want to 'change it' on every click? [ocanal's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10172947/82548) will only change it once.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<a>` elements cannot contain interactive content.

Comment: @Quentin: Quite true. @ user: See the content model of the [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-a-element.html#the-a-element), which links to the definition of [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#interactive-content). This is unrelated to your question, but still a useful thing for Quentin to point out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".tabs").click(function() {
   $(this).attr("href","newhref.com");
});
```

**UPDATE**

---

you can get attribute value like this,

```
$(this).attr("href")  //will return '#educationDetails'
```

so you can check that value like this,

```
$(".tabs").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("href") == "#tab1")
      $(this).attr("href","#tab2");
  else if ($(this).attr("href") == "#tab2")
      $(this).attr("href","#tab1");
});
```

**UPDATE-2**

---

If you just want to change #tab1 to #tab2, not reverse. you can also do it like this way,

```
$('a.tabs[href="#tab1"]')​.click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href","#tab2");​
})​;​
```

Comment: can you please show me how I can use the switch condition to see it the current `href` value is this "#tab1" then set it to "tab2". Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @user1211185 If this is the correct answer to your question you should mark this as the answer

Comment: Hi Jayanga, I tried to mark it but it says I can mark it after 10 minutes may be I don't have enough reputations. thanks

Comment: It's your question, [you can accept any answer to any of your own question(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts) (which rewards you with a measure of rep). All you have to do is wait for the timer to clear and allow you to do so.

Comment: @ocanal no I have 7 tabs on my page and there is no previous button at the moment. I am just moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.tabs").click(function() {
    this.href = 'newhref';
    return false;
});
```

It is more efficient this way compared to @ocanal solution.

Source:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/

Comment: If you're going to make that claim, might I recommend you pay a visit to [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/) and provide support/evidence? (You're right, but...y'know, cite your sources. =))

Comment: @DavidThomas. The source... http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/

Comment: "Please note that there are three attributes that should always be accessed, via jQuery: “src,” “href,” and “style.” These attributes require the use of getAttribute in older versions of IE."