# How to dynamically change href in javascript each time user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML file which has href attribute which should change dynamically each time the user clicks. But it is not happening here. I am using accordions using bootstrap here. Please see the below code.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" translate>
 <div class="row">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-1">{{week.weekNo}} </label> 
<label class="control-label col-sm-6">{{week.weekStartDate}}
            {{week.weekEndDate}}</label> 
<i  class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"
style="margin-right: 15px"></i>
</div>
</a>
```

How am I supposed to do that?
I have gone through few methods to change href dynamically but nothing worked for me. Please help me.

Comment: Can you share those methods ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172933/how-to-change-html-links-href-property-dynamically. This is one of the method.

Comment: This will work just fine. Can you share your code so that one can make out what is going wrong ?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the developer tools console when you use your variation of the code (clearly you can't use exactly that code as the class is different for a start)

Comment: @ Jaromanda X Yes. though I change the class name it is not working. What am I supposed to initialize to href and where exactly should I place this function?

Comment: @JaromandaX, My guess is OP is mixing jQuery with angular..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script>
   var new_href="http://somelink.com";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#link_id").attr("href", new_href);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

new_href Here you can store the link everytime you need to set dynamically.

Comment: what should be the link_id here in my case

Comment: the id of the anchor or link button where you are setting the href

Comment: if you are using class use .classname and if id then use #id